# Exception in internal-nlog when returning a File(MemoryStream) from a controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

After updating my app to .net core 3.1, I started noticing new logs in the internal-nlog files such as:

```
2020-07-23 23:49:07.0858 Warn Failed to get property value for object: System.IO.MemoryStream Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
   at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at NLog.Internal.ObjectReflectionCache.ObjectPropertyList.Enumerator.get_Current()
```

The app itself is functional and working, it is just that this log pops up.

I managed to track it down to an nlog update from 4.5.6 to 4.7.2. After some playing around I came to the conclusion that the log entry does not appear on nlog 4.5.11, and it starts to appear on nlog 4.6.0

The log entry is written (twice) after exiting a particular controller action. It can be summed up as:

```
var stream = generateMemoryStream();
return this.File(stream,mediatype,somefilename);
```

The possibly relevant nlog config chunk is below

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="jsonFile" fileName="Logs\nlog-json-${shortdate}.log" >
      <layout type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}"/>
        <attribute name="templatedMessage" layout="${message:raw=true}" />
        <attribute name="exception" encode="false">
          <layout type='JsonLayout'>
            <attribute name="message" layout="${exception:format=message}" />
            <attribute name="type" layout="${exception:format=shortType}" />
            <attribute name="stackTrace" layout="${exception:format=stackTrace}" />
            <attribute name="data" layout="${exception:format=Data}" />
          </layout>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false">
          <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="2"/>
        </attribute>
      </layout>
    </target>
```

Has anyone else noticed this behaviour? Or can point me in a certain direction?

Comment: The extra "noise" was introduced with https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2989 (Before this PR then NLog suppressed any exceptions coming from doing reflection).

Comment: NLog 4.7.3 will reduce the noise with https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/4043 and https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/4057

Comment: I did see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2989 but i was not quite sure on that i only did a quick scan but noticed more 'reflection' to get properties so that was flag. Great that you made a pull so fast to simply not include streams, as this makes the most sense. I am not dependent on anything higher than 4.5 at this moment so i'll upgrade as soon as 4.7.3 comes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until NLog 4.7.3 is released then you can prevent reflection of Stream-objects with the following code:

```
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupSerialization(s => 
   s.RegisterObjectTransformation<System.IO.Stream>(o => o.ToString()));
```

This will remove the noise coming from NLog trying to perform property-reflection of `Stream`-objects.